# Hashcode Of a String

Tags: java, string, object

When we try to print any object using `toString()` we get the HashCode (if `toString()` is not overriden). But, If I want to print the Hashcode of the String Variable, what should I do.
This question it is with respect to Java.

Comment: What do you mean by "hash code of the String variable"? Why can't you simply call `hashCode()` on it?

Comment: `toString()` doesn't just print the hashCode() by default. You are better off calling `hashCode()` if that is what you want.  Note: it might not be unique.

Comment: you don't get the hashcode, you get the objectId.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx And what would objectid be, this is not a standard Java term?

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx: ok I meant the object id. thnx

Comment: @BiswanathChowdhury So, do you want to print the object id of your String, or the hashcode? :)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - That is a nice catch, that the default `hashCode()` implementation may not be unique for all objects.

Comment: @PetarMinchev There is **no such thing** as a unique `hashCode` implementation, except for objects whose total number of possible states fits into an `int`. Such objects are **very rare**.

Comment: There are many Strings with the same hashCode. ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310498/why-doesnt-strings-hashcode-cache-0

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx : what do you mean by "it is not a standard Java term" ?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik `Integer` as a key isn't that rare. ;)

Comment: @Marko Topolnik - Yep, it comes from the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: @BiswanathChowdhury I think he means, there is no globally unique id for an object you can print out.

Comment: @BiswanathChowdhury The term "objectid" has no standard meaning in Java. The specification does not define it and it is not even in general use. Maybe there is some other programming language where that term is well-known, but Java is not such a language.

Comment: @PeterLawrey : can you please elaborate me on this. " default hashCode() may not be unique". Thnx

Comment: I know that objectid is not a term in Java, I must have misleaded you. It was used because I honestly didn't knew the exact term.

Comment: @BiswanathChowdhury If you follow the link I gave, it lists multiple Strings with a hashCode() of 0. Empty string also has a hashCode of 0.

Comment: @BiswanathChowdhury There is no exact term because its not something which exists in Java.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I think that by "objectId", Joeri Hendrickx means the value returned by `System.identityHashCode(___)`. (If so, (s)he's mistaken -- `Object.toString()` actually uses the hash-code from `hashCode()`, not the identity-hash-code -- but even so, that's what I think (s)he means.)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Indeed, I was wrong; for some reason, I thought the default toString showed the object id (the one you see through jdb), but indeed, it's the hashcode.

Comment: @BiswanathChowdhury Note additionally that even `identityHashCode` is not guaranteed to be unique on today's systems, since a `long` would be required to fit all the address space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is an objects hashcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237720/what-is-an-objects-hashcode)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just call `hashCode()` on the `String` object:

```
String s = "Hello World";
System.out.println(s.hashCode());
```

If you want it in the same format as `Object.toString()`, try this:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(s.hashCode()));
```

Comment: More precisely: `s.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(s.hashCode());`

Comment: @assylias Yes ofcourse: `"String@" + Integer.toHexString(s.hashCode()));`

Comment: @Jesper: ok, hashCode() is the member of the object class. Thnx.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the hash code of any Java object by invoking the `hashCode()` method. The result will be an `int` that you can then print or do anything else you want with it.

If you are interested in the implementation of `Object.toString`, it is very easy to check at [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#236). It says:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("Some String".hashCode());
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply call the `hashcode()` method. It comes from `Object`.

```
String str = "mystring";
System.out.println(str.hashCode());
```