# Performance warning in Guava ImmutableMap

Tags: java, guava

In the javadocs for Guava's ImmutableMap it says:

> Performance notes: unlike HashMap, ImmutableMap is not optimized for
>   element types that have slow Object.equals(java.lang.Object) or
>   Object.hashCode() implementations. You can get better performance by
>   having your element type cache its own hash codes, and by making use
>   of the cached values to short-circuit a slow equals algorithm.

So my first question is how do I know if my element has a slow .equals or .hashCode implementation? In my specific instance, I'm using a java Enum as my key, so that has an efficient default implementation of .equals and .hashCode, right? (I assume the implementation of those for the values is irrelevant so long as you aren't accessing the map using the values' values.)

My second question is what does "having your element type cache its own hash codes" even mean! Googling around I couldn't seem to find an example of how you would do that. I assume maybe that means you end up with hashcodes within hashcodes? So I get into the hashcode bucket, and then the .equals methods uses a second set of hashcodes within that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm using a java Enum as my key, so that has an efficient default implementation of .equals and .hashCode, right?

Neither equals or hashcode are overriden so it could hardly be much faster (i.e. equals returns `this == other`).

> My second question is what does "having your element type cache its own hash codes" even mean!

You could have something like the code below, to avoid multiple calculation - if you do that, you need to make sure that:

- the hashcode is invariant (i.e. can't change throughout the life of an instance)
- your `hashcode` method is thread safe (which can be done with the use of a local variable for example or more simply by making `hash` volatile).

```
class MyClass {
    private int hash;

    public int hashcode() {
        int hash = this.hash;
        if (hash == 0) {
            hash = calculateIt();
            this.hash = hash;
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the object is immutable and hashcode() / equals() is often called, you can even compute the hashcode during the object's construction and not worry about thread-safety anymore.

Comment: @FrankPavageau Absolutely - that is much easier and safer indeed.

Answer (score 2):

If your key is an `Enum` then this is not an issue for you.

What they are talking about with caching hash codes would be something like:

```
private volatile int hashCode = -1;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  if ( hashCode == -1 ) {
    hashCode = longCalculation();
  }
  return hashCode;
}
```

Comment: Of course, you have to be careful that -1 isn't a valid hash value. `java.lang.String` has this problem: some strings will recalculate their hashes every time.

Comment: @assylias - You are right - to an extent. Actually it **is** safe but it **is** possible to call the `longCalculation` multiple times if multiple threads request the `hashCode` at the same time. If that is a critical issue then I would certainly put more effort into this method in a multi-threaded environment. It does, however, clearly demonstrate the point I am making.

Comment: So what they mean is you save the hashcode as an instance variable so you don't need to repeatedly calculate it? Basically, you sacrifice some memory (extra instance variable) to enhance the performance by caching the value.

Comment: @CorayThan - Yes! That is what they mean by caching the value.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Actually technically it could erroneously return -1 because of instructions reordering. This is why String#hashcode uses a local variable for example.

Comment: @assylias - FTFY (in a much more natural way I suspect) - I still fail to see how thread safety is a factor here. IMHO If we tried to make all of our code thread safe we would soon bring productivity to a halt.

Comment: @Antimony relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310498/why-doesnt-strings-hashcode-cache-0/

Comment: @assylias Actually, even if `hashCode` isn't volatile, it will still never erroneously return -1. Instructions in the same thread are guaranteed to executed as if in program order. At worst, you'll have longCalculation called multiple times, but it will never actually return -1.

Comment: @Antimony Not when using a shared variable with improperly synchronized accesses. See for example: http://jeremymanson.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/benign-data-races-in-java.html (third code example).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old question, but for those who got here like me - you really should be using an `EnumpMap`, if your key is an enum.