# What is the time complexity of Java hashCode method for the String class?

Tags: java

Is Java's hashCode method for String class computed in constant time or linear time? What is the algorithm used?

Comment: How about reading the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode--)?

Answer (score 10):

The documentation tells you the function:

> s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]

It's computed once using a linear-time pass, and then cached so it's only O(1) to retrieve it in the future.

Comment: Unless [the result is 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310498/why-doesnt-strings-hashcode-cache-0) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29)

> public int hashCode()
>
> Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a String object is computed as
>
> ```
>     s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
> ```

As you can see, the time complexity is the O(n) where n is the number of characters in the string. After one pass, it is cached so the time complexity is effectively O(1).

Comment: This answer is incomplete/misleading, because it doesn't take caching into consideration. The caching makes the complexity effectively amortized O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Time Complexity of `Object::hashCode` method is O(1), because it has no any interaction with the data of your object. It is a native method and written with C language. The integer value which is returned, is probably heap memory address with some modifications (bitwise operations) since every address in memory representing unique value.

For example 4GB memory addresses will be represented in hexadecimal format from `0x00000000` to `0xffffffff` range and each of this value is unique. Thus, Java does not require extra computation to ensure uniqueness of these values. Therefore `hashCode` gives constant time complexity.